# How to download all pdf files from multiple urls python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using `Python`, I'd like to download all pdf files(except names that begin by "INS") from website

```
url_asn="https://www.asn.fr/recherche?filter_year[from]={}&filter_year[to]={}&limit=50&search_content_type=&search_text={}&sort_type=date&page={}"
```

`if link['href'] is not pdf`, then open it and download pdf files if they exist - for each page, interate to last page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

probably this will work?
I have added comments for every line.

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = " " # url to scrape

#If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
folder_location = r'/webscraping' # folder location
# create folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)
 
response = requests.get(url) # get the html
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser") # parse the html 
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"): # select all the pdf links
    #Name the pdf files using the last portion of each link which are unique in this case
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1]) # join the folder location and the filename
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f: 
# open the file and write the pdf
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
```

Comment: It'll work for first page, not for all pages (loop need to be iterate until last page for each content), at the same time it'll download files with names "ISN".  it'll be pleasure to use regex like this"^((?!ISN).)*$".

Comment: I thought multiple URLs in the sense of multiple sites  , about using regex I just demonstrated feel free to use whatever floats your boat I was trying to explain as easy as possible.

Comment: for example f"https://www.asn.fr/recherche?filter_year[from]={date.today().year - 10}&filter_year[to]={date.today().year}&limit=50&search_content_type={content}&search_text={query}&sort_type=date&page={page}". Firstly, I have to find last page for each content and query